# Count by group and condition on a number in R

Tags: database, dplyr, count, sum, mutate

I have the following dataset:

```
      id_municipio  year  Vivo  Claro   TIM     Oi Algar Sercomtel  MVNO
         <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl> <dbl>
1      1100015  2009  65.4  13.0   28.2   90.8     0         0     0
2      1100023  2009 775.  154.   334.  1076.      0         0     0
3      1100031  2009  35.2   6.98  15.2   48.8     0         0     0
4      1100049  2009 634.  126.   273.   880.      0         0     0
5      1100056  2009 122.   24.2   52.6  169.      0         0     0
6      1100064  2009 135.   26.7   58.2  187.      0         0     0
```

I want to create another column by `"id_municipio"` and `"year"` which add 1 if the remaining columns have a value bigger than 0. Here is what a I to have:

```
id_municipio  year  Vivo  Claro   TIM     Oi Algar Sercomtel  MVNO total Providers
         <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>
1      1100015  2009  65.4  13.0   28.2   90.8     0         0     0  197.         0
2      1100023  2009 775.  154.   334.  1076.      0         0     0 2339.         0
3      1100031  2009  35.2   6.98  15.2   48.8     0         0     0  106.         0
4      1100049  2009 634.  126.   273.   880.      0         0     0 1912.         0
5      1100056  2009 122.   24.2   52.6  169.      0         0     0  368.         0
6      1100064  2009 135.   26.7   58.2  187.      0         0     0  407.         0
```

I know it would be something like this but I am stuck:

```
library(dplyr)
dataset %>% group_by(id_municipio, year) %>% mutate(Providers =...)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can sum across columns in a row matching the condition:

```r
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union

df <- structure(list(
  id_municipio = c(1100015, 1100023, 1100031, 1100049,
                   1100056, 1100064),
  year = c(2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2009),
  Vivo = c(65.4, 775, 35.2, 634, 122, 135),
  Claro = c(13, 154,
            6.98, 126, 24.2, 26.7),
  TIM = c(28.2, 334, 15.2, 273, 52.6, 58.2),
  Oi = c(90.8, 1076, 48.8, 880, 169, 187),
  Algar = c(0, 0, 0,
            0, 0, 0),
  Sercomtel = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
  MVNO = c(0, 0, 0,
           0, 0, 0)
), row.names = c(NA,-6L), spec = structure(list(
  cols = list(
    id_municipio = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
                                               "collector")),
    year = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
                                       "collector")),
    Vivo = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
                                       "collector")),
    Claro = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
                                        "collector")),
    TIM = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
                                      "collector")),
    Oi = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
                                     "collector")),
    Algar = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
                                        "collector")),
    Sercomtel = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
                                            "collector")),
    MVNO = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
                                       "collector"))
  ),
  default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess",
                                        "collector")),
  delim = ","
), class = "col_spec"), class = c("spec_tbl_df",
                                  "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

df %>%
  group_by(id_municipio, year) %>%
  mutate(Providers = rowSums(across('Vivo':'MVNO') > 0))
#> # A tibble: 6 × 10
#> # Groups:   id_municipio, year [6]
#>   id_municipio  year  Vivo  Claro   TIM     Oi Algar Sercomtel  MVNO Providers
#>          <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>
#> 1      1100015  2009  65.4  13     28.2   90.8     0         0     0         4
#> 2      1100023  2009 775   154    334   1076       0         0     0         4
#> 3      1100031  2009  35.2   6.98  15.2   48.8     0         0     0         4
#> 4      1100049  2009 634   126    273    880       0         0     0         4
#> 5      1100056  2009 122    24.2   52.6  169       0         0     0         4
#> 6      1100064  2009 135    26.7   58.2  187       0         0     0         4
```

<sup>Created on 2022-11-29 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Hello, Seth. I did a command based on your but it is not working:

providers %>%
     group_by(id_municipio, year) %>%
     mutate(Providers = rowSums(across('Vivo':'MVNO':'Claro':'TIM':'Oi':'Algar':'Sercomtel':'MVNO') > 0))

Comment: Hi Mateus, could you please edit the question to include a sample of the `providers` data frame? You can paste the output from `dput(providers)` directly.

Comment: Hey, Seth. The dataset is too long, so I used the command "head". I think now it is better.

Comment: I understand. In the future, you can pass a subset of your data to dput, e.g. `dput(head(providers,20))`. Using the updated data in the question, my original answer still works for me. If the columns in your full data set are the same as in the question, please try the code in the answer, replacing `df` with your data frame's name. `across('Vivo':'MVNO')` will operate across all provider named columns, and you should not need to list them separately. I updated my answer to include the data I am testing with, for comparison.